# Openai gym environment for multi-agent games

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Is it possible to use [openai](https://openai.com/)'s [gym environments](https://gym.openai.com/docs) for multi-agent games? Specifically, I would like to model a card game with four players (agents). The player scoring a turn starts the next turn. How would I model the necessary coordination between the players (e.g. who's turn it is next)? Ultimately, I would like to use reinforcement learning on four agents that play against each other.

Comment: I am trying the same, hopefully using keras-rl.

Comment: Coming back to my question after a while, it looks like https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib.html is a fairly interesting library to do multi-agent reinforcement learning using Openai gym environments

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use OpenAI gym environments for multi-agent games. Although in the OpenAI gym community [there is no standardized interface](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/934) for multi-agent environments, it is easy enough to build an OpenAI gym that supports this. For instance, in OpenAI's [recent work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02275.pdf) on multi-agent particle environments [they make a multi-agent environment](https://github.com/openai/multiagent-particle-envs/blob/master/multiagent/environment.py) that inherits from `gym.Env` which takes the following form:

```py
class MultiAgentEnv(gym.Env):

    def step(self, action_n):
        obs_n    = list()
        reward_n = list()
        done_n   = list()
        info_n   = {'n': []}
        # ...
        return obs_n, reward_n, done_n, info_n
```

We can see that the `step` function takes a list of actions (one for each agent) and returns a list of observations, list of rewards, list of dones, while stepping the environment forwards. This interface is representative of [Markov Game](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring07/cps296.3/littman94markov.pdf), in which all agents take actions *at the same time* and each observe their own subsequent observation, reward.

However, this kind of Markov Game interface may not be suitable for all multi-agent environments. In particular, turn-based games (such as card games) might be better cast as an *alternating* Markov Game, in which agents *take turns* (i.e. actions) one at a time. For this kind of environment, you may need to include which agent's turn it is in the representation of state, and your step function would then just take a single action, and return a single observation, reward and done.

Comment: Will a turn-based step function work for games where the rewards are not "zero-sum"? Perhaps this has more to do with the design of the agent than the environment. Seems like in non-zero-sum games, agents could learn to collude with one another give each other artificially higher scores, leaking collusion information through the environment.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is [PettingZoo](https://github.com/PettingZoo-Team/PettingZoo), it's a set of environment with multi agent setting and they have a specific class / synthax to handle multi agent environment.

It's an interesting library because you can also use it with ray / rllib to use already implemented algorithm like PPO / Q-learning. Like in this [exemple](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/multi_agent_independent_learning.py).

[Rllib](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/env/multi_agent_env.py) also have an implementation for multiagents environments. But you will have to dig deeper in the documentation to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a multi-agent deep deterministic policy gradient MADDPG approach has been implemented by OpenAI team.

This is the repo to get started.
https://github.com/openai/multiagent-particle-envs

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific multi-agent environment for reinforcement learning [here](https://github.com/hilkoc/ai_arena). It supports any number of agents written in any programming language. An example game is already implemented which happens to be a card game.